# Regular expression to find decimal numbers in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to search a string that has embedded decimal numbers. The number uses comma for (hundred / thousand separator) and dot for decimal separator.

**Example of invalid decimal numbers:**

- .33, .333 (Number must be preceded with at least 1 digit albeit zero)
- 1,22,33.33, 1,22.333 (last segment in comma separated digits must have 3 digits)
- .3, .3333 (Decimal number must have 2 or 3 digits after decimal)
- ,0.33 (Decimal number must not start with comma)

**Example of valid decimal numbers:**

- 0.33 & 10.333
- 1,22,333.33 & 1,222.333

**Special case:** If the string is like "You a/c bal.33.33". The result should be 33.33

---

I have tried following regex:

```
 (((\\d+\\,)+\\d{3})|([^,]\\d+))\\.\\d{2,3}(?!\\.\\d)
```

It works for all cases but fails when number has leading comma.

Comment: No it must have decimal part. See invalid example 3.

Comment: So `1,2,3,4,5,666.78` is valid?

Comment: @anubhava: yes, in the given example above. Ideally only first segment can have single digit, all segment in between should have either 2 or 3 digits, but last segment must have 3 digits.

Comment: As you said in the last point of invalid decimal number, it must fail when the number has a leading comma, so what is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use capture groups as

```
/(?:[^\d,]|^)(\d+(?:(?:,\d+)*,\d{3})?\.\d{2,3})\b/
```

- Capture group 1 , `(\d+(?:(?:,\d+)*,\d{3})?\.\d{2,3})\b` will contain the decimal number in the string.
- `(?:[^\d,]|^)` ensures that the the capture group correctly captures the entire digits and not part of it.

[**Regex Demo**](https://www.regex101.com/r/sE2sC5/3)

**Test**

```
var str = "0.33";
var matches = str.match(/(?:[^\d,]|^)(\d+(?:(?:,\d+)*,\d{3})?\.\d{2,3})\b/);
console.log(matches[1])
=> 0.33

var str = "You a/c bal.33.33"
var matches = str.match(/(?:[^\d,]|^)(\d+(?:(?:,\d+)*,\d{3})?\.\d{2,3})\b/);
console.log(matches[1])
=> 33.33
```

Comment: Thanks NullPointer! It works perfectly.

Comment: @closure Glad to hear it helped :D. Please make sure you use a `if ( matches)` statement to take care of cases where the string is not matched by your regex.

Comment: This match numbers like 1,222.3 & 1,222.3556 & 1,22,333,444.15

Comment: @VasilNikolov Oops missed that. corrected in answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Just try with following regex:

```
^\d+((,\d+)*,\d{3})?\.\d{2,3}$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/vD4dC6/1)

Comment: Brilliant. but fails for special case given above.